# error in knn imputation [R] - is logical supported?

Tags: r, r-caret, imputation

I tried `caret` and `DMwR` for imputation. They both gives error

```
Y = 35

impu = preProcess(dat[, -Y], method = c('knnImpute'))
dat1 = predict(impu, newdata = dat[, -Y])
# Error in `[.data.frame`(old, , non_missing_cols, drop = FALSE) : 
#         undefined columns selected


dat1 = knnImputation(dat, scale = T, meth='median')
# Error in scale.default(xcomplete, dm[i, ], FALSE) : 
#         length of 'center' must equal the number of columns of 'x'
```

The data has numeric, factor, and logical columns.

Please download data [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9EHYRPZSyc8eF9XZ1hsbUlSV1E/view?usp=sharing) and load it with `load('data2013.RData')`
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is no `Y` column in your `dat` dataframe. You can use instead:

```
impu = preProcess(dat, method = c('knnImpute'))
dat1 = predict(impu, newdata = dat)
```

Comment: Without data, I can't reproduce

Comment: @HubertL thanks for your answer. I updated OP and added the data, please try it and maybe you can figure out what was going on for us. Thanks a lot!